# Countrows in Summarized DAX Table Variable

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have the following simplified DAX measure.  The real world example does a lot of heavy lifting to end up at the information that's in `var t1`

Here's the example for set up in DAX Studio:

```
EVALUATE

var t1 = DATATABLE("item", STRING, {{"a"}, {"b"}})

return
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            t1,
            [item]
        ),
        "count", calculate(countrows(t1))
    )
```

This query returns a table with a count of 2 for each item, a and b.

If I were to create the simplified table in the data model and use the query it would return the correct result with a count of 1 for each item, a and b.

I understand that the reason is that t1 is a constant and that the two references to the t1 in the query are seperate references and therefor the filter context is different on the two instances.

Is there a way to do this using the table `var t1` or do I need to solve this in a different method?

Current incorrect output:
[item],[count]
a,2
b,2

Expected output:
[item],[count]
a,1
b,1

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you're trying to achieve. What is your objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a FILTER like this:

```
ADDCOLUMNS (
    SUMMARIZE ( t1, [item] ),
    "count", COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( t1, [item] = EARLIER ( [item] ) ) )
)
```

Using [GROUPBY](https://dax.guide/groupby/) is cleaner for this sort of thing, IMO.

```
GROUPBY ( t1, [item], "count", SUMX ( CURRENTGROUP(), 1 ) )
```

Comment: Thank you.  Both of these options work.  Now I have a few more DAX functions to add to my toolbelt.

Comment: Nice, Alexis, very clean!

Comment: @Alexis Olson,  can u help me on this measure i have posted yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74075291/powerbi-measure-in-x-axis-has-numerical-value-and-change-slicer-by-measure-value